# How can I use a Javascript variable as a DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is kinda hard to word so i'm hoping you understand it:

I have an entire page in a variable. I need to be able to do getElementsByClassName on it. But how?

I've tried:

```
$.get( base_url, function( data ) {
 var something = data.getElementsByClassName('.user_name');
});
```

Comment: how about `data.getElementsByClassName('user_name');` no dot

Comment: what are the values of `base_url` and `data`?

Comment: Niang oh that might be it. I had user_name in a jQuery $() with the . to find classes. Let me try that real quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your URL returns HTML, `data` is a string. Since you're using jQuery, you can have jQuery parse it for you:

```
var dom = $(data);
```

Then you can use all the usual jQuery methods on that disconnected set of elements, so:

```
var userNames = dom.find(".user_name");
```

If you *weren't* using jQuery, you could have the browser parse that into elements for you:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = data;
```

...and then use use DOM methods on that disconnected div. I wouldn't use `getElementsByClassName`, though; `querySelectorAll` has better support; basically, it's in all modern browsers and also in IE8, but IE8 doesn't have `getElementsByClassName`.

```
var userNames = div.querySelectorAll(".user_name");
```

Comment: @AaronDigulla: OMG do I need more coffee.

Comment: My guess is he's not aware of this fact ;-)

Comment: @TJ: Out of interest, how do browsers like injecting a *complete* HTML page (complete with doctype and `<html> tags etc.) into a `div`?) I'm not sure what the OP means with *I have an **entire** page in a variable*.

Comment: Well I don't need to put it in the page.

Comment: @Matt: They take the descendants of `head` and `body` and put them in the `div`. So for instance, if you do `div.innerHTML = "<!doctype html><html><head><title>Foo</title></head><body><p>one</p><p>two</p></body></html>";`, you'll end up with `div.innerHTML` being `"<title>Foo</title><p>one</p><p>two</p>"` or similar. Much better, if you're using jQuery, to use jQuery's more robust processing.

Comment: @user3349060: Not following you. Nothing in the answer above puts anything in the page.

Comment: @Matt: np. :-) I've always wondered why `DocumentFragment` never got an `innerHTML` property or `insertAdjacentHTML` function; it would make stuff like this *so much more reasonable*. Instead of a `div`, you can use an `html` element and maintain `head` and `body` content separation -- except it fails on IE (where `div` doesn't). **sigh**

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing pure javascript with JQuery

Try this

```
 data.getElementsByClassName('user_name');
```

instead of

```
 data.getElementsByClassName('.user_name');
```